# How do you update the Bamboo build number from the build script?

Tags: bamboo

When I run my build script from TeamCity I can output `##teamcity[buildNumber '<new build number>']` and TeamCity will update the build number accordingly.

How can I do this in Bamboo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - at least not in a supported way.
Even ignoring the build script portion of your question, Bamboo simply doesn't support editing of build numbers like TeamCity does.

[Here's the feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-10282)

If you really want to edit the build number, you may be able to do it manually (at your own risk!) with a few SQL queries. [This post](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/22152/reseting-build-numbers-in-bamboo) from Atlassian's forums should help you get started.